# Macaw multiple routes for slug

Tags: php, routes

I've using [Macaw](https://github.com/NoahBuscher/Macaw) a PHP router class.

I trying to figure out a way to call a route with a filter (:any) then do a comparison inside a closure and if no match found have a second route, the code below will run only for the first route as expected, I don't know a way to tell the Macaw class to look at the second route.

```
//match any request again a case inside the closure
Macaw::any('(:any)', function($slug)(){

    if($slug == 'sample'){
        //match
    } else {
       //somehow go to the next route
    }

});

//otherwise look here
Macaw::any('(:any)', function(){
    //do something
});
```

What I'm aiming to do is have the last route look run of no routes before if have a match inside their own closured.

Essentially I would like any url to be routed to multiple closures to check for matches (they will be coming from plugins) then if no match if found call the last route.

### UPDATE

I've just noticed in slim you can do the following that is exactly what I need

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/Frank', function () use ($app) {
    echo "You won't see this...";
    $app->pass();
});
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) use ($app) {
    echo "But you will see this!";
});
$app->run();
```

I know I could include slim but as I only want the routing that would be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! calling a haltOnMatch stop or returns the flow so I can do the following:

```
Router::any('(:all)', function($request){

    if($request == 'blog'){
        echo 'match';
    } else {
        //go to next route
        Router::haltOnMatch(false);
    }

});
```

This way I can use multiple Router::any('(:all)' calls.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
Macaw::get('/(:any)', function($slug){
    echo 'Hello World!';
});

Macaw::get('/(:any)/', function($slug){  // Required for url ends with '/' (eg: domain.com/foo/ )
    echo 'Hello World! ' . $slug;
});

Macaw::get('/(:any)/(:any)', function($slug, $slug2) {
    echo 'The slug is: ' . $slug2;
});
```

Comment: thanks I see where your going, that's no use to me, I'll be loading some of the routes via plugins so I won'r know what the structure will always be.

Comment: that's why I would like to have multiple any ruotes that can somehow detect if their is a match inside of them.

I may need to restructure my application

Comment: Try this:


Macaw::get('/(:all)', function($slug){
 echo 'The slug is: ' . $slug;
});